# Auto-Label in scatter plot using matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, label

so in continuation of my problem a while ago, having this suggested program:

```
%// Input
A =[
    2   1   5
    1   3   10
    1   -2  5
    0   5   25
    5   0   25
    1   1   2
    -1  -1  2]

[unqcol3,unqidx,allidx] = unique(A(:,3),'stable')
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,3),unqcol3.'),1)  %//'
out =[A(unqidx,:) counts(:)]
scatter(out(:,3), out(:,4))
```

so it will generate an array and a plot like this:

```
     a     b     d     counts
     2     1     5     2
     1     3    10     1
     0     5    25     2
     1     1     2     2
```

d vs. counts

[image]

but i want to put (a,b) as a labels on each scatter point, so this the plot out put i want:

[image]

so as you can see the corresponding a,b will automatically labelled on each scatter points, please help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using `sprintf` and a simple for loop.

Complete code:

```
clear
clc


A =[
    2   1   5
    1   3   10
    1   -2  5
    0   5   25
    5   0   25
    1   1   2
    -1  -1  2]

[unqcol3,unqidx,allidx] = unique(A(:,3),'stable');
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,3),unqcol3.'),1);
out =[A(unqidx,:) counts(:)]
scatter(out(:,3), out(:,4));

    %// This step is not necessary but its easier to understand using it.
    a = out(:,1);
    b = out(:,2);
    x = out(:,3);
    y = out(:,4);

for k = 1:size(out,1)

    T{k} = sprintf('%i%i',a(k),b(k))

end
%// Determine x- and y-shift to place text relative to the scatter point
xshift = 0.03; yshift = 0.03;

%// Place the text
text(x+xshift, y+yshift, T);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: yep just remove them in the call to `sprintf`

Comment: why are your labels didn't match my labels? where (22) label came from and so on?

Comment: No problem @Divakar! I just saw that I made a mistake in the labels! It was the first 2 columns instead of the last 2 d'oh thanks to you I did notice :)

Comment: @nobel sorry I previously used the wrong columns for labeling. Now its fixed

Comment: so how can i fix that?

Comment: ok so "out" function only applies in 4x4 array, how but 4x5? or m x n? thanks.

Comment: well it depends on what data you want to plot and what label you need to use. In that case you can change a,b,x and y.

Comment: what if my data is a,b,c,x,y?

Comment: use `T{k} = sprintf('%i%i%i',a(k),b(k),c(k))`

Comment: i try, but it gives an error: Attempted to access out(:,5); index out of bounds because size(out)=[4,4].

Error in xrd (line 40)
    y = out(:,5);

Comment: As the message says, your data is not 4 x 5 but 4 x 4 so there is no 5th column

Comment: yes, you're right, i just want to extend my data into 4x5 matrix, anyways thanks a lot :))

Answer (score 1):

After you have `out`, you can use this `no-loop approach` -

```
%// Plot points and set x-y limits
scatter(out(:,3), out(:,4),'o')
xlim([0 30]), ylim([0 2.5])

%// Create string labels
L = cellstr(strcat(strtrim(num2str(out(:,1))),strtrim(num2str(out(:,2)))))

%// Set some y-shift and put text labels
y_shift = 0.1
text(out(:,3),out(:,4)+y_shift,L)
set(gca,'YGrid','on')
```

Code run -

[image]