# how to change size(out) = [m n] in matlab

Tags: matlab, size, label

This is a continuation  of my previous problem, so now i want to know how to change array size and how to use size(out) = [m n].

so basically if you have 10x10 array and you want to plot column 9 vs. column 10 in scatter plot, and you want column 1-column 8 to be the labels of your scatter plot. how can i use size(out) = [10 10]?

for someone who want examples:

[Auto-Label in scatter plot using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650118/auto-label-in-scatter-plot-using-matlab/28650376?noredirect=1#comment45598369_28650376)

and what if your array is m x n? is there a general code for this? please enlighten me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things more general you can make use of the [end](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html?refresh=true) keyword, which refers to the last row/column or an array/cell array/anything in Matlab (actually "last array of index").

Revisiting your example, you could use `num2str` (alternatively to `sprintf`) and use the following:

```
scatter(out(:,end-1), out(:,end));

for k = 1:size(out,1)

T{k} = num2str(out(k,1:end-2));

end

xshift = 0.03; yshift = 0.03;

text(out(:,3)+xshift, out(:,4)+yshift, T);
grid on
```

Which gives this:

[image]